# How do you create a global array of strings?

Tags: c++

How do you create a global array of strings? I have tried declaring a string outside of main and dynamically initializing it using `myString = new string[5];`, but I receive the error "No viable overloaded '='" in Xcode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet is a little terse, but if your full declaration is

```
string myString = new string[5];
```

then the problem is that you are trying to assign an *array* of strings to a variable that's only designed to hold *one* particular string. You'll want to do

```
string *myStrings = new string[5];
```

where the global variable contains a *pointer* to the first string in the array -- or

```
string myStrings[5];
```

where the global variable *is* the array.

Comment: Or better yet, `vector<string> myStrings;`

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
char const *myStrings[] = {
    "Some",
    "Strings"
};
```

Comment: this is the lightest solution for storing a list of keywords at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use curly brace notation to initialize an array:

```
std::string myString[5] =
{
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
    "string4",
    "string5"
};
```

If you're simply trying to declare and allocate it, all you need is:

```
std::string* myString = new std::string[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure `myStrings` is a pointer i.e `string* myStrings` not `string myStrings`